# Google Data Studio (BigQuery) from 1 to 01

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

How do I left zero pad numbers in BigQuery, which will produce a string value?

For example, the input `8` should produce `08` and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For BigQuery, you can use:

`select format("%02d", n)`

e.g. `select format("%02d", 8)`

=> `08`

Answer (score 3):

BigQuery specifically offers `lpad()`:

```
select lpad(8, 2, '0')
```

Although `format()` can do the same thing, this is a function that is available in multiple other databases (I'm not sure if it is formally part of the standard).

Comment: Running this query gives me: No matching signature for function LPAD for argument types: INT64, INT64, STRING. Supported signatures: LPAD(STRING, INT64, [STRING]); LPAD(BYTES, INT64, [BYTES]) at [1:8]

Comment: this works (in BigQuery): `LPAD('8',2,'0')`